# Apply style and template controls in c# WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, styles

I would like to apply a custom style(template) to a button, textbox, textBlock ect.. 
Where i can learn this in Visual Studio 2010 (i use c# wpf)? 
Could you give me examples?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how `Caliburn.Micro` comes into picture here. It's more of a question about UI/XAML/Blend tutorial...

Comment: Sorry edit question ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does [this tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/Styles.html) answers your question ?

It is simple but shows you the use of `window.resources` for WPF styles.